# How can I map inside another map, getting index of each first map?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dictionary

I have two arrays, one is an ID array eg.:

```
fonogramas = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
```

Array to store informations:

```
rank_completo = []
```

and the second is a JSON array eg.:

```
rank = [ { Tocadas: 1424,
    Artista: 'Felipe Araújo',
    id_Artista: 1663,
    Musica: 'Atrasadinha - Feat. Ferrugem - Ao Vivo',
    id_Musica: 44337,
    Mes: 1,
    Dia: 30,
    Tipo_Emissora: 2,
    Categoria_Radio: 'FM' },
{ Tocadas: 1356,
    Artista: 'Gabriel Diniz',
    id_Artista: 1642,
    Musica: 'O Nome Dela é Jennifer',
    id_Musica: 43158,
    Mes: 1,
    Dia: 30,
    Tipo_Emissora: 2,
    Categoria_Radio: 'FM' } ]
```

I need to map the first array for each ID and find on second array WHERE are they, this below is my code that is bringing `-1`:

```
fonogramas.map( ef => {
    rank_completo.push(`{ ${rank.map( er => { er.Musica; }).indexOf(ef.id)}, ${ef.id}}`);
});
```

Thank you!!

EDIT 1:

What I expect is:

```
rank_completo = [{id: 5, rank: 3},{id: 2, rank: 1},{id:1, rank:2},{id:4, rank: 4}]
```

EDIT 2: Match example

```
ef.id = 44337
```

I have an array with two elements, above those two elements the `ef.id` is the first one, so my results should be

```
rank_completo=[{id: 44337, rank: 0}]
```

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Comment: In your JSON there is no `id` key ? what are you matching ?

Comment: @CodeManiac id_Musica

Comment: @NinaScholz done

Comment: What is `{id: 5, rank: 3},{id: 2, rank: 1}` in the output? Your input has `44337` as id. Please provide actual inputs, outputs and a clear problem statement to create a [mcve]

Comment: Did that, put real example

Comment: What is the purpose of `fonogramas` if you're assigning  `44337` to rank `0`? Is `rank` = `index` of the item?

Comment: rank is the same as the `indexOf()`, if the index of `44337` is 37 so the array would be `rank_completo=[{id: 44337, rank: 37}]`

Comment: You should use `const rank_completo = fonogramas.map(…)`, not `push` inside the `map` callback

Comment: So, why did you create a `fonogramas` with random `id`s which don't exist in the `rank` array? It wastes everybody's time. Please create a [mcve] from next time onwards. You might also want to read the [Stack Overflow question checklist by Jon Skeet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply map the rank array with `id_Musica` and the index of fonogramas' value.

```js
var fonogramas = [1, 2, 3, 44337, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 43158],
    rank = [ { Tocadas: 1424, Artista: 'Felipe Araújo', id_Artista: 1663, Musica: 'Atrasadinha - Feat. Ferrugem - Ao Vivo', id_Musica: 44337, Mes: 1, Dia: 30, Tipo_Emissora: 2, Categoria_Radio: 'FM' }, { Tocadas: 1356, Artista: 'Gabriel Diniz', id_Artista: 1642, Musica: 'O Nome Dela é Jennifer', id_Musica: 43158, Mes: 1, Dia: 30, Tipo_Emissora: 2, Categoria_Radio: 'FM' }],
    rank_completo = rank.map(({ id_Musica }) =>
        ({ id_Musica, rank: fonogramas.indexOf(id_Musica) }));

console.log(rank_completo);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
rank_completo = rank
    .map( 
        (r, i) => ({
            rank: i,
            id: r.id_Musica
        })
    );
```